# SSRS 2008 R2 - calculate Top 5% 10%, 20% etc in dynamic range in matrix

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, matrix, report, expression

I need to calculate the Top 5%, 10%, 20% and then the bottom 5%, 10%, 20% in a dynamic range in a matrix in SSRS 2008 R2.

So I have data like this in my matrix:

```
               Week1    Week2   Week3   Week4
Time  09:00     27       405     2       18
      10:00     12       1      1008     1098
      11:00     1002     10      76      102
```

So across those values I need to work out which of them fall into the top 10%, the bottom 10% or whatever. So if I were to add all of the numbers together shown above I would have a total of 3761. The range of individual values falls between the lowest amount (1) to the highest (1098). So how do I work out what % 'slot' 405 falls into and how do I make the report work this out when the numbers will be dynamic? I then need to use this calculation to highlight cells with some conditional formatting...

Any help gratefully received and thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your source for this data SQL Server? You might be better served using some of the RANK() and NTILE() windowing functions to determine each value's rank within the dataset there.

Comment: Thanks, my source is SQL Server 2008 R2 - I can see how NTILE() may work on the SQL level but ideally I need the equivalent function but in SSRS itself...?

Answer (score 0):

I would add a "Percentile" column to the SQL query using the NTILE function.  Beware the gotchas with NTILE which I described in the "Community Additions" section:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx